# Swing change JScrollPane content

Tags: swing, jscrollpane

Hi I am trying to change `JScrollPane` content like

```
scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(new Welcome().display());

        for(final JMenuItem i : items) {
            i.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String txt = i.getText();

                    if(txt.equals("Open")) {
                        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(new Open().display());
                    } else if(txt.equals("Save")) {
                        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(new Save().display());
                    } else if(txt.equals("Save as")) {
                        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(new SaveAs().display());
                    } else if(txt.equals("Close")) {
                        new Close().ask();
                        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();
                    }

                    scrollPanel.revalidate();
                    scrollPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
        }   

        scrollPanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.add(scrollPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

But its not working.
Each class Open, Save, SaveAs return `JPane` with `JLabel` inside.
Ex.

```
public class Open {
    public JPanel display() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Open"));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not changing the scrollpane content. You're assigning a new JScrollPane instance to the `scrollPanel` field. The scroll pane you have added to the frame and which is displayed stays exactly as it is.

If you want to change the scroll pane contents, you should use

```
scrollPanel.setViewportView(new Open().display());
```